# Preserve Input Values when switching between views in React

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, react-router

Situation: I have a several input components but depending on the route (react-router) different ones are shown.

Problem: I want the input values the user already entered to be preserved when switching back and forth between routes and dropping/re-adding input components.

I came up with two solutions so far: 1) Always render everything but hide via CSS if not to be shown (breaks the idea of React for me somehow)
2) Implement some kind of "input value store" in the flux architecture (pretty elabortate)

Any other ideas? Am I missing something more fundamental?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely go for the second approach, something Flux like. But if this is the only thing in your application that needs it, you can keep it very simple. Should be possible to implement in very few lines of code.

The benefit you get is that the Flux approach scales very well, so you won't have to rewrite it if the application grows.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Dynamic Segments

> If you have dynamic segments in your URL, a transition from /users/123 to /users/456 does not call getInitialState, componentWillMount, componentWillUnmount or componentDidMount. [React-Router-Guide](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/overview.md)

You should use dynamic routes like this example:

```
<Route name="inbox" handler={Inbox}>
  <Route name="message" path=":messageId" handler={Message}/>
  <DefaultRoute handler={InboxStats}/>
</Route>
```

If you change the messageId(child component) you will still have the same state in the Inbox(parent) Component.

It will look something like this:

```
<Route name="search" path="/search/:query?/:limit?/:offset?" handler={Search} />
```